# Access/Update Variable in Main UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

### Question

How do I *properly* update a variable/state in a UITabBarController from a deeply nested view without a nightmare chain of delegation?

### Background

My app is set up with a main UITabBarController which holds a number of UINavigationControllers (one for each tab) which then hold various other view controllers (it could get as deep as a custom control in a cell in a UITableViewController). I'm not using IB - it's all created programmatically.

It can essentially look like this at any given time (as an example):

```
MainTabBarViewController
 -> UINavigationController
  -> CancelOnboardingButton (UIBarButtonItem) // should update variable
  -> PackagesOverviewViewController (UIPageViewController)
   -> PackagesListTableViewController (UITableViewController)
    -> PackagesListItemTableViewCell (UITableViewCell)
     -> CompleteOnboardingButton (UIButton) // should update variable
```

In my custom UITabBarController (class: MainTabBarController), I have a variable that should switch which UINavigationControllers are set for the tabs based on whether the user has completed onboarding for that package. So if the user were to hit the `CompleteOnboardingButton` button, the variable in `MainTabBarViewController` is updated (see below), the tabbar changes, and life is good.

Of course, MainTabBarController has no knowledge of the UIButton, and various actions might update the MainTabBarController variable (eg, a button click at the end, a cancel button click throughout, etc).

```
class MainTabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

  var firstRun : Bool = true
  ...
  func goToProgram(_ programID: String){
    if firstRun {
      // First present the onboarding screens
      // At the end, these should update firstRun to false
    } else {
      setViewControllers([array_of_tabs], animated: true)
    }
  }
}
```

### What I've Tried

I've tried a few solutions like `self.tabBarController?.firstRun` and `self.navigationController?.tabBarController.firstRun` which (a) crash my app and (b) require my custom buttons to know *where* they are (which is not desirable).

I have done something like this:

```
let vc : MainTabBarViewController = MainTabBarViewController()
vc.firstRun = false
```

...but I don't think that's right for reason b above *and* it reads like it's creating a new instance (I'm coming from a PHP background, but I'm guessing it's the same idea here?)

I've tried `.addTarget(nil, action: #selector(someSelector), for: .touchUpInside)` to let it bubble up, but XCode complains that `someSelector` isn't in the class holding the button (I thought I could just add the `someSelector` function in `MainTabBarViewController` and it would catch it there).

I can use `NotificationCenter`, but that requires my `MainTabBarViewController` to know buttons are present to listen for (so I don't have open observers).

And, of course, I have to believe there's an easier way to pass state/actions up the view chain without adding delegates and protocols through each view controller.

What am I missing here? How do I *properly* update a variable/state in a UITabBarController from a deeply nested view?

Comment: I would use `NotificationCenter`, I'm not sure what your issue is with open observers. If you are worried about the observers being present once you've made the switch, you can just remove them when the switch occurs?

Comment: Thanks! I don't have an issue with them - I'm just not sure if that's the right way to pass state changes around in this setup?

Comment: My suggestion is to **not** hold application-wide state in any view controller.  Create a Model class to hold the data and access it through a shared instance.  The model can then send "state changed" notifications or can be a passive repository that gets queried, depending on your preference or your app's structure.

Comment: @PhillipMills - thanks! When you say "state changed notifications", are you also suggesting `NotificationCenter` as Flexicoder recommended?

Comment: If you want to go the notification route, yes.  Usually, controllers can simply ask the data model for what they need when they need it.  Notifications are more appropriate for situations where data may change dynamically while a controller's views are on-screen.